# inserting a new row instead of updating the current row

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

hi I am having problem with the code below
I am doing ajax and if the data is exactly same it doesnt insert a record. But if the text in text area changes, it should update the record, but instead it inserts a new row.

here is my model

```
<?php 
class Test extends AppModel {

    var $belongsTo = array('table1','table2');

        var $validate = array(
            'field1' => array(
                'rule' => 'duplicateCheck',
                'message' => 'Duplicate record'
            ),
            'textbody' => array(
                'rule' => 'duplicateCheck',
                'message' => 'Duplicate record'
            )
        );

        function duplicateCheck() {
            $conditions = array(
                'Test.field1' => $this->data['Test']['field1'],
                'Test.textbody' => $this->data['Test']['textbody']
            );
            return !$this->hasAny($conditions);
        }

}
?>
```

and here is my controller

```
<?php

function add() {

        if(isset($this->data)) {

        if($this->Test->save($this->data['Test'])) {

        } else {


            if(isset($this->Test->validationErrors['field1'])) {



            }
        }
    }



}   

?>
```

not sure how I can tackle this
thanks

**EDIT**

ok I change it to this  but now it wont update the field

```
var $belongsTo = array('table1','table2');

    var $validate = array(
        'field1' => array(
            'rule' => 'duplicateCheck',
            'message' => 'Duplicate record'
        ),
        'userid' => array(
            'rule' => 'duplicateCheck',
            'message' => 'Duplicate record'
        )
    );

    function duplicateCheck() {
        $conditions = array(
            'Test.field1' => $this->data['Test']['field1'],
            'Test.userid' => $this->data['Test']['userid']
        );
        return !$this->hasAny($conditions);
    }
```

}
?>

Comment: shouldn't that be save($this->data)? Otherwise best trying w/o complication of ajax first, easier to check the sql logs etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are passing the PK to the $this->Model->save() or it will create a new ID for the PK field. Also, the $this->data should be sent to the save as $this->data with the name of the model included. So if your model name is Test, try sending it like:

```
$this->Test->save($this->data)
```

NOT

```
$this->Test->save($this->data['Test'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If $this->data['Test']['id'] has a value, the save function will update the record instead of creating a new record.

Since you will only update record if Test.field1 is already in the table, you need to do another checking inside the add() function:

```
function add() {
    if(isset($this->data)) {
        $existingRecordId = $this->Test->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('Test.field1' => $this->data['Test']['field1']),
            'fields' => array('Test.id')
        ));
        if(sizeof($existingRecordId)>0)
            $this->data['Test']['id'] = $existingRecordId['Test']['id'];
        if($this->Test->save($this->data['Test'])) {
        } else {
            if(isset($this->Test->validationErrors['field1'])) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your model:

```
'field_name' => array(
        'alphanumeric' => array(

            'rule' => array('isUnique'),

            'message' => 'Percentage Commision already set for this api',

            'allowEmpty' => false,

            //'required' => false,

            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule

            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations

        ),
```

Suppose you have a field called "field_name". then in your model you can just put a validation rule and it will take care automatically.